# creating ajsf/primefaces page programmatically

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I need to create a page programmatically and print it for a user. The page can have one or many data tables, based on user input from another page.

I can't seem to find examples of how to achieve this

Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean a list of multiple datatables? If so ui:repeat will be usefull

Comment: @Makky currently there isn't any code add I am unable to find examples to even get started.

Comment: @AkselWillgert I changed the question so that it shows what I want to achieve. Perhaps there is a better solution than my plan of action.

Comment: so the question is "how to add data tables dynamically ,right ?"

Comment: Correct. Either add datatables or create the whole page either one will suffice